# Does anyone know why I'm getting a segmentation fault after the returning value of a RPC function?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, return-value, rpc

I have a RPC program which implements two method:

```
   1): int * delete_occurrences_1(char **, CLIENT *);
   2): ListDir * subdirectory_list_1(char **, CLIENT *);
```

with ListDir defined as:

```
#include <linux/limits.h>
#define N 6

struct DirectoryName{
    char nameD[PATH_MAX]; //PATH_MAX=4096
};

struct ListDir{
    DirectoryName directories[N];
    int cont;
};
```

in the client, when the function `subdirectory_list_1` is called i get segmentation fault in the same line, even though the server side sends it correctly or at least set the structure with the correct value.

Here's the code of the client RPC (line 65 gives me seg fault):

```
#include "RPC_xFile.h"
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFF 256

int main(int argc,char ** argv){
    if(argc!=2){
        printf("Name Program , ipAddress");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    CLIENT * cl;
    char * host;
    int * result;
    ListDir * out =(ListDir *) malloc (sizeof(ListDir));
    if (out == NULL) {
        perror("Errore durante l'allocazione di memoria per ListDir");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    out->cont=0;
    char choiche[BUFF];
    host = argv[1];
    char * path = (char*) malloc(PATH_MAX);
    cl = clnt_create(host, RPC_XFILE, RPC_XFILEVERS, "udp"); //fondamentale FATTOREX E FATTOREXVERS STESSI DEL FILE.X
    if (cl == NULL) {
        clnt_pcreateerror(host);
        exit(1);
    }
    char * pos;
    printf("Avviato servizio RPC\n");
    printf("Inserire:\n");
    printf("E - per eliminare le occorrenze numeriche da un file di testo specificato presente lato server\n");
    printf("L - per avere la lista dei sottodirettori di primo di livello contenenti almeno 5 file di testo dato un direttorio\n");
    printf("ctrl^D per terminare\n");
    while(fgets(choice,sizeof(choice),stdin)!=NULL){
        if ((pos=strchr(choice, '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0';
        switch(choice[0]){
            case 'E':
                    printf("Dimmi il nome del file da esaminare\n");
                    fgets(path,PATH_MAX,stdin);
                    if ((pos=strchr(path, '\n')) != NULL)
                        *pos = '\0';
                    result = delete_occurences_1(&path, cl);
                    if(*result == -1){
                        printf("File inesistente oppure problemi di creazione/modifica file\n");
                    }
                    else{
                        if(*result == 0){
                            printf("Nel file non sono state trovate occorrenze numeriche\n");
                        }
                        else{
                            printf("Nel file sono state rimosse %d occorrenze numeriche\n",*result);
                        }
                    }
                break;
            case 'L':
                    printf("Dimmi il nome del direttorio\n");
                    fgets(path,PATH_MAX,stdin);
                    if ((pos=strchr(path, '\n')) != NULL)
                        *pos = '\0';
                    out = subdirectory_list_1(&path,cl);
                    printf("Ricevuto risultato");
                    if(out->cont == -1){
                        printf("Directory non trovata oppure problemi gestione file lato server\n");
                    }
                    else if(out->cont == 0){
                        printf("Non sono state trovate sottocartelle di primo livello che soddisfano tali specifiche\n");
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("Sottocartelle di primo livello trovate:\n");
                        for(int i=0;i<out->cont;i++){
                            printf("%s\n",out->directories[i].nameD);
                        }
                    }
                break;
            default:
                printf("Servizio non disponibile, inserire E o L\n");
        }
        printf("Inserire:\n");
        printf("E - per eliminare le occorrenze numeriche da un file di testo specificato presente lato server\n");
        printf("L - per avere la lista dei sottodirettori di primo di livello contenenti almeno 5 file di testo dato un direttorio\n");
        printf("ctrl^D per terminare\n");
    }
    free(out);
    free(path);
    clnt_destroy(cl);
    printf("Programma terminato\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

for completeness, wishing that anyone could solve my problem, I paste also The server the `.x` file and the `.h` file.

Server:

```
#include "RPC_xFile.h"
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DIM 256

int * delete_occurences_1_svc(char ** nameFile, struct svc_req * rq){
    static int result=0;
    int fd=open(*nomeFile,O_RDONLY);
    if(fd<0){
        printf("Errore apertura file %s\n",*nomeFile);
        result=-1;
        return &result;
    }
    char tempFile[DIM];
    int cont=0;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(*nameFile);i++){
        if((*(*nameFile)+i)=='.')
            break;
        else
            cont++;
    }
    if(cont==(strlen(*nameFile))){
        strcpy(tempFile,"temp.txt");
    }
    else{
        memcpy(tempFile,*nameFile,cont);
        strcat(tempFile,"_temp.txt");
    }
    printf("Creo file temporaneo %s\n",tempFile);
    int tempFd=creat(tempFile,O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(tempFd<0){
        printf("Errore creazione file temporaneo %s\n",tempFile);
        close(fd);
        result=-1;
        return &result;
    }
    char temp;
    while(read(fd,&temp,1)>0){
        if(temp<'0' || temp>'9'){
            write(tempFd,&temp,1);
        }
        else{
            result++;
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    if(rename(tempFile,*nameFile)<0){
        printf("Modifica avvenuta con successo, ma errore avvenuto nella modifica del nome file temporaneo\n");
        close(tempFd);
        result=-1;
        return &result;
    }
    printf("Modifica avvenuta correttamente, eliminati %d numeri\n",result);
    return &result;
}

int EndsWith(char *str, char *suffix)
{
    if(strlen(str) >= strlen(suffix))
    {
        if(!strcmp(str + strlen(str) - strlen(suffix), suffix))
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

ListDir * subdirectory_list_1_svc(char ** nameDir, struct svc_req * rq){
    static ListDir out;
    out.cont=0;
    char pwd[PATH_MAX];
    char finallyDir[PATH_MAX];
    if(strlen(*nameDir)<=0){
        printf("Errore input nome direttorio\n");
        out.cont=-1;
        return &out;
    }
    if((*nameDir[0])=='/'){
        strcpy(finallyDir,*nomeDir);
    }
    else{
        if(getcwd(pwd,sizeof(pwd))==0){
            printf("Errore getcwd\n");                             //restituisce pwd
            out.cont=-1;
            return &out;
        }
        
        snprintf(finallyDir,PATH_MAX,"%s/%s",pwd,*nameDir);
    }
    DIR * dir;
    out.cont=0;
    dir=opendir(finallyDir);
    if(dir==NULL){
        printf("Directory non trovata\n");
        out.cont=-1;
        return &out;
    }
    struct stat statFile;
    struct dirent * dr;
    char filePath[PATH_MAX];
    char filePath2[PATH_MAX];
    DIR * dir2;
    struct dirent * dr2;
    int contAllow=0;
    while((dr=readdir(dir))!=NULL && out.cont<6){
        snprintf(filePath,PATH_MAX,"%s/%s",finallyDir,dr->d_name);
        if(stat(filePath,&statFile)<0){
            printf("Errore con stat file\n");
            closedir(dir);
            out.cont=-1;
            return &out;
        }
        else if(S_ISDIR(statFile.st_mode)){
            dir2 = opendir(filePath);
            if(dir2==NULL){
                printf("Apertura directory %s null\n",filePath);
                out.cont=-1;
                return &out;
            }
            else{
                while((dr2=readdir(dir2))!=NULL && contAllow<5){
                    snprintf(filePath2,PATH_MAX,"%s/%s",filePath,dr2->d_name);
                    if(stat(filePath2,&statFile)<0){
                        printf("Errore con stat file\n");
                        closedir(dir);
                        closedir(dir2);
                        out.cont=-1;
                        return &out;
                    }
                    else if(S_ISREG(statFile.st_mode)){
                        if(EndsWith(dr2->d_name,".txt")==1){
                            contAllow++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(!(contAllow<5)){
                    strncpy(out.directories[out.cont].nameD,filePath,PATH_MAX);
                    out.cont++;
                }
                contAllow=0;
                closedir(dir2);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return &out;
}
```

file.x:

```
#include <linux/limits.h>
#define N 6

struct DirectoryName{
    char nameD[PATH_MAX];
};

struct ListDir{
    DirectoryName directories[N];
    int cont;
};

program RPC_XFILE {
    version RPC_XFILEVERS{
            int DELETE_OCCURENCES(string) = 1;
            ListDir SUBDIRECTORY_LIST(string) = 2;
    } = 1;
} = 0x20000013;
```

file.h:

```
#define RPC_XFILE 0x20000013
#define RPC_XFILEVERS 1

#if defined(__STDC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
#define DELETE_OCCURENCES 1
extern  int * delete_occurences_1(char **, CLIENT *);
extern  int * delete_occurences_1_svc(char **, struct svc_req *);
#define SUBDIRECTORY_LIST 2
extern  ListDir * subdirectory_list_1(char **, CLIENT *);
extern  ListDir * subdirectory_list_1_svc(char **, struct svc_req *);
extern int rpc_xfile_1_freeresult (SVCXPRT *, xdrproc_t, caddr_t);

#else /* K&R C */
#define DELETE_OCCURRENCES 1
extern  int * delete_occurrences_1();
extern  int * delete_occurrences_1_svc();
#define SUBDIRECTORY_LIST 2
extern  ListDir * subdirectory_list_1();
extern  ListDir * subdirectory_list_1_svc();
extern int rpc_xfile_1_freeresult ();
#endif /* K&R C */

/* the xdr functions */

#if defined(__STDC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
extern  bool_t xdr_DirectoryName (XDR *, DirectoryName*);
extern  bool_t xdr_ListDir (XDR *, ListDir*);

#else /* K&R C */
extern bool_t xdr_DirectoryName ();
extern bool_t xdr_ListDir ();

#endif /* K&R C */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* !_RPC_XFILE_H_RPCGEN */
```

thank you for the attention

Comment: These statements         memcpy(tempFile,*nomeFile,cont);
        strcat(tempFile,"_temp.txt"); already invoke undefined behavior because the array tempFile does not contain a string.

Comment: And my advice: use English words for identifiers. In this case your code will be more readable for others.

Comment: Also pay attention to that this variable static int result=0; is initialized only once and keeps its value between function calls.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you're right about english word for identifiers, i just change it hopefully that's gonna be more readable, by the way the two advise that you gave me are about the other function which works

Comment: The UB in the server could be causing the RPC response to be malformed, which then causes the seg fault when the client tries to parse it.

Comment: @Barmar could you explain what you mean by 'UB'

Comment: UB = Undefined Behavior, which Vlad already mentioned.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you were right, handling tempFile as a string has made my program works correctly, thank you! By the way is very strange that a problem inside one function gave seg fault with the other, even though they're independent.